# Why didn't site design change after the launch?

Tags: discussion, design

According to Area 51, [Islam.SE is launched.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam) Given that, why is the site design the same as beta design?

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our Community Managers from last week: [Custom Islam Stack Exchange design and logo - Information gathering](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3576/46770) :)

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3649/46770)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It used to be that a new design was a part of the graduation process. Unfortunately, as the Stack Exchange network expanded, this led to more and more sites having their graduation delayed while waiting on the new design to be developed. Eventually, the number of sites that needed a new design far outpaced the resources available for developing those designs.

Some time ago, it was decided instead that graduation going forward would be [design-independent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/132874):

> Phase 1
>
> ---
>
> *The Community Team announces that a site is cleared for graduation. Without delay...*
>
> - the beta label is removed
> - elections are held
> - migration paths are set up
> - community ads are run
>
> ### Phase 2
>
> *Then, as it becomes available:*
>
> - the site gets their custom design.
> - privilege thresholds are increased to graduated site levels

As for how long until it "becomes available", your guess is as good as mine. All I know is that the community team has been stretched rather thin over the last year or so, so it might still take a while.

Comment: I see, thank you. I really like to ask my question in here once a while, but I guess there are not too many people who're actively replying. I am hoping a fancier design will attract more users :)